# php date() and expiration date()

Tags: php, date, datetime, timestamp

I am creating an application in PHP that will allow the user to create  a 'post' that initially lasts for 7 days and the user can add increments of 7 days at any time. I ran into a snag in working with the php date('Y-m-d H:i:s') function and adding days to an already established start date that is pulled from the datebase after the 'post' has been initiated...

```
$timestamp = "2016-04-20 00:37:15";
$start_date = date($timestamp);

$expires = strtotime('+7 days', $timestamp);
//$expires = date($expires);

$date_diff=($expires-strtotime($timestamp)) / 86400;

echo "Start: ".$timestamp."<br>";
echo "Expire: ".$expires."<br>";

echo round($date_diff, 0)." days left";
```

That is what I have so far and it's not doing very much for me. Could anyone show me an example of the right way to do this?

Comment: You are falling in two common pitfalls: use strings to handle dates and assume calculations are so straightforward that you don't need date functions (`/86400`). Also, your code should trigger a notice (*A non well formed numeric value encountered*) you apparently cannot see: that means that you haven't configured your development box to display error messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost had it, you forgot to convert the $timestamp to a timestamp before adding the 7 days.

```
$timestamp = "2016-04-20 00:37:15";
$start_date = date($timestamp);

$expires = strtotime('+7 days', strtotime($timestamp));
//$expires = date($expires);

$date_diff=($expires-strtotime($timestamp)) / 86400;

echo "Start: ".$timestamp."<br>";
echo "Expire: ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $expires)."<br>";

echo round($date_diff, 0)." days left";
```

Comment: it's already a string, he forgot to turn it into a timestamp.

Comment: That's what I missed. Awesome, It clicks in my head now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One possible way:

```php
/* PHP/5.5.8 and later */
$start = new DateTimeImmutable('2016-04-20 00:37:15');
$end = $start->modify('+7 days');
$diff = $end->diff($start);
```

You can format `$diff` to your liking. Since you appear to need days:

```
echo $diff->format('%d days');
```

([demo](https://3v4l.org/AJcgL))

For older versions, the syntax is slightly more convoluted:

```php
/* PHP/5.3.0 and later */
$start = new DateTime('2016-04-20 00:37:15');
$end = clone $start;
$end = $end->modify('+7 days');
$diff = $end->diff($start);
```

([demo](https://3v4l.org/OHu2u))